# Verb forms with "I"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I am totally confused in the usage of pronoun "I". We use the verb "have" with "I" not "has" though it is singular. "I" is singular but again we don't use (s, es, ies) with the verb while making the sentence of present simple tense.

Comment: That's right. Yes it's odd. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

The inflection with *-s* is used **only** in the simple present and **only** with the third person singular, not with the first person (the person speaking) or second person (the person addressed).

> {I / we / you / they }  {have / run / push / &c}
>     {he / she / it}   { ha**s** / run**s** / push**es** / &c}

One verb, *BE*, employs an inflection with *-s* (was) in the simple past for both first and third person singular; but *BE* is quite different from all other verbs.

A few verbs, the modals *can/could, may/might, must, shall/should, will/would* are *defective*: they have **no**  inflection with *-s*, even in the present third person singular. They also lack participles, and the 'plain' form is never used as an infinitive or imperative.

Comment: Thnx but I am confused with the pronoun "I".       Why we use has with he, she, it, singular name?? Answer is that the subject is singular, so my question is that the pronoun "I" is also singular, so why we use have with pronoun "I"?

Comment: Thnx I got it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about 'singular' and 'plural' pronouns doesn't really help you here. In English, *meaning* (including 'singular' and 'plural') doesn't always match up with *grammar* (including verb agreement).

Thinking about 'singular' and 'plural' *may* help with regard to {she/he/it has} (singular) and {they have} (plural). It certainly doesn't help in thinking about {you have} (singular) and {you have} (plural) - 'you' takes the 'plural' verb whether I am talking to one person or more than one person.

And it doesn't help with 'I' (singular in meaning but plural in grammar (most of the time)) and 'we' (plural in meaning and plural in grammar).

Some words just work differently. StoneyB has mentioned verb *BE* as working differently from other verbs. In different ways, the pronouns 'I' and 'you' work differently from other pronouns, in particular in terms of verb agreement.